# How to create forms based on fields in database in java?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb

Suppose I have a table in my DB called student and it fields are Name, Address, Age, Class.
My question is that is it possible to autogenerate a form to insert values into the table, without me physically coding the form in HTML or JSP, hence a change in the table will reflect on my form.

I have done the same in php symfony framework, is this possible in java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using JDeveloper and the Oracle ADF Framework. If you want to use them try this [tutorial][1]: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18941_01/tutorials/jdtut_11r2_56/jdtut_11r2_56.html Point 6 and 7 should do what you want.